# Installation location selection screen - Ubuntu Server 18.04.3

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I manage to get through all of the installation screens during the Ubuntu 18.04.3 Server install, up until the drive and partition selection screen, where it says there is a problem. I have attached the installer logs (linked from paste.ubuntu.com) which I hope will describe the issue better, as I do not know how to properly interpret the logs. From what I can tell, there is a drive issue because of the Python error output whilst it is looking at the filesystem, but I can't get much further than that.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/shPKXTFFsb/
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qyJ5yHHRcF/
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9N3yHnX3QG/
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Vzxn3fSddQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your logs https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qyJ5yHHRcF/

```
"Couldn't find partition entry in table")
RuntimeError: Couldn't find partition entry in table
```

Which looks similar to this https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1841333/comments/3, from issuer's comment:

> I was using the "live" version, and the alternative installer does work.

The alternate `.iso` can be found http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.4/release/. Although this issue has been suggested as being a compatibility issue, not a bug in the comments, it seems for now installing the alternative image is worth a try.